# Gnerating !N/A Error in Excel for Null Data from Access DB

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, excel

I want to generate #N/A error in Excel for the null data I get from Access DB.

This is continuing on from [Crosstab query: Getting Null Data for Missing Data from Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862358/crosstab-query-getting-null-data-for-missing-data-from-access-db).

Now I got data in this format in Access DB and I can get the data in following format in Excel:

```
myDate    South   West   East
11/1/2013 10      20     10
11/2/2013 10      20     10    
11/3/2013                  
11/4/2013 10      30     10
```

But I want to put #N/A error, so that the average function that calculate over this value will over be #N/A which will let me know quickly if there is missing value.

So I want result to be like

```
myDate    South   West   East
11/1/2013 10      20     10
11/2/2013 10      20     10    
11/3/2013 #N/A    #N/A   #N/A          
11/4/2013 10      30     10
```

I can't seem to get around this.

What I thought of using **NZ** function to capture null value and put #N/A, but I think it would only put string "#N/A" which is not what I want because Excel just skips the string value in calculation. I want it to be Excel error #N/A.

Is there anyway how I can do this?

All I can think about now is to have if statement in Excel VBA to check the region to see if there is null values and replace them with #N/A error. But I want the Excel worksheet to be clean and have little code as much as possible.

Is there another way?

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a string `#N/A` will be recognized properly by calculations. Try populating multiple cells with numbers then choose one cell and manually type in `#N/A`. It ***will not*** be skipped. Put in something not recognized by Excel like `BK201` or whatever and it ***will*** be skipped.

Screenshots:

**Some random text inserted into range:**

[image]

**`#N/A` manually typed into cell:**

[image]

There is no green triangle and you can see in the formula bar that it's typed into the cell. Basically, a string `#N/A`. However, notice that the `AVERAGE` function at the bottom now errors out.

Also, based on what I've read about the `NZ` function, I don't think it has an equivalent in Excel. The best way here is to use a subroutine that replaces all the blank cells with `#N/A`. Here's a simple and clunk-free code.

```
Sub ReplaceWithNA()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10") 'Modify as necessary.
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Len(Cell) = 0 Then
            Cell.Value = CVErr(2042)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Let us know if this works. :)

Comment: Thank you for the great info, indeed just string #N/A does error out calculation. Let me get back to you after I actually try applying to my case.

Comment: It worked! I used your with slight modification to send worksheet name and range as argument. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the excel functions:

- If
- IsBlank
- NA()

So in the following test jesus did not score:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If you don't want a second table with functions in them then you could still use this function as follows:

```
Sub UsingVBA()

Dim x As Integer
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(Excel.xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(3, 4), .Cells(x, 4)).Value = "=IF(ISBLANK(C3),NA(),C3)"
    .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(x, 3)).Value = .Range(.Cells(3, 4), .Cells(x, 4)).Value
    .Range(.Cells(3, 4), .Cells(x, 4)).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but in my case, I was looking to more of query or Excel VBA code to get #N/A error because I don't want to have duplicate data in my worksheet.

Comment: using `VBA`, using my example, you could put the function in the range D3:D5 and then paste the values onto C3:C5 ...then delete the functions.

Comment: @green0range I've edited answer with a possible way to use the function within `vba` so a second table is not required

Comment: Thank you for the info. This could be another option, and you reminded me that I could use formula in the code too! But I think in this case, BK201 answer suited me better. Thanks for the help!

Comment: (@green0range it's ok (some might say polite) to up-vote anything that helps or might help others....not that I'm worried about points!)

Comment: I don't have enough point to up-vote. Sorry I will upvote when I get to 15 points.

Comment: @green0range no worries - I up-voted the question but not quite enough!